# Sending a git commit with aptana shows "commit by unknown" in github.com

Tags: github, aptana, git-commit

I set up Aptana 3 under windows 7 using egit more than a year ago.

I put my settings to :
preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration:

```
user.name = My Name
user.email = myName@myCompany.com
```

so in 
D:\web.metadata.plugins\com.aptana.portablegit.win32\etc\gitconfig

i can find these lines 
[user]

name = My Name
email = myName@myCompany.com

and the same in :
C:\Users\MY username.gitconfig

i did this by this commands in git Bash:

```
$ git config --global user.name "My Name "
$ git config --global user.email "myName@myCompany.com"
```

this worked perfect until last October.

Now: when i do a commit to any file and after this a git push, in github i can see my name as the one you had send the push, but the commit is show as "unknown" (all commits before october are perfect)

Reinstalling my system in december (what was needed because of switching from w7/32-bit to w7/64bit) does not bring help.

on my colluege on same repository it still works (but he is using aptana under mac so there is shure a diffrence in settings..)

i today updated to latest version of egit :
  Eclipse EGit  2.2.0.201212191850-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 
with no change ..

(for me it looks like i got this since version 
2.1.0.201209190230
that i installed at the end of September, but as the PUSH always shows my name i did not notice that it was missing at the commit ..

so:any hints are welcome ..
joerg

EDIT:
When i use the Git GUI i alos installed, and use the button "sign" i get that additional line in the commit:

`Signed-off-by: myName <myName@myCompany.com>`